# MySql: Getting sum of a table by the id of its parent from other table and return all children with sum values that are relevant to parent_id

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance

Imagine these are my database's tables:

```
Table #1: child
╔══════════╦═════════════════╦═══════╗
║Child_id  ║Primary key - AI ║ int   ║
╠══════════╬═════════════════╬═══════╣
║parent_id ║Index-Forign_key ║ int   ║
║══════════╬═════════════════╬═══════╣
║title     ║        -        ║varchar║                   
╚══════════╩═════════════════╩═══════╝
```

---

```
Table #2: Paid
╔══════════╦═════════════════╦═══════╗
║Paid_id   ║Primary key - AI ║ int   ║
╠══════════╬═════════════════╬═══════╣
║child_id  ║Index-Forign_key ║ int   ║
║══════════╬═════════════════╬═══════╣
║paid_price║        -        ║int    ║                   
╚══════════╩═════════════════╩═══════╝
```

---

Here are my tables value:

```
Table: child (data)
╔══════════╦══════════╦═══════╗
║ Child_id ║parent_id ║ title ║
╠══════════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ 1        ║25        ║bla-bla║
║══════════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ 2        ║25        ║bla-bla║
║══════════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ 3        ║5         ║bla-bla║
║══════════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ 4        ║25        ║bla-bla║
╚══════════╩══════════╩═══════╝

 Table: paid (data)
╔══════════╦══════════╦════════════╗
║ Paid_id  ║Child_id  ║ paid_price ║
╠══════════╬══════════╬════════════╣
║ 1        ║1         ║100         ║
║══════════╬══════════╬════════════╣
║ 2        ║2         ║250         ║
║══════════╬══════════╬════════════╣
║ 3        ║1         ║35          ║
║══════════╬══════════╬════════════╣
║ 4        ║1         ║17          ║
╚══════════╩══════════╩════════════╝
```

I have a query that returns (get) all child_id from child table, then by that ids return sum paid_price of each of them.

This is my query:

```
SELECT child.Child_id, child.parent_id, sum(paid.paid_price)
FROM paid
JOIN child ON child.Child_id = paid.Child_id
WHERE child.parent_id =25
group by child.Child_id, child.parent_id
```

**[RESULT AND DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b5dfd7/5/0)**

**I WANT THIS**: Now my query is working well, but when there is no `child_id` in the `paid` table, the query don't return it.
I mean I want all `child_id` weather they are in `paid` table or not. if they are not return 0  *(now I think it is null and does not return)*

Please see my demo (link above) and see that if I enter `parent_id=25`  it will return 2 rows (sum), because `child_id = 3` does is not exist in `paid` and does not return it in result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need here is a LEFT JOIN (and reverse the order of the tables) or a RIGHT JOIN which is less common:

```
select
  parent.Child_id,
  parent.parent_id,
  coalesce(sum(paid.paid_price), 0)
from
  parent left join paid
  on parent.Child_id = paid.Child_id
where
  parent.parent_id =25
group by
  parent.Child_id,
  parent.parent_id
;
```

a LEFT JOIN will return all rows from the table on the left, and all matching rows from the table on the right. If no match, the columns from the table on the right will be null.

Coalesce will return the first non null value, so if sum() is null it will return 0 instead.