# how to use sum and join the 3 tables using laravel6?

Tags: jquery, mysql, laravel

I have 3 tables, salaries table `salaries(id, name)` and pointages table `pointages(id, datep, salarie_id, sold)` and avances table `avances(id, datea, montantA, salarie_id)`.

table salaries

```
Id  name
1   kamal   
2   imad
```

pointages table

```
id  datep       Salarie_id  sold
1   11/03/2020      1        120
2   05/03/2020      1        100
3   06/03/2020      2        50
4   07/03/2020      2        20
```

avances tables

```
id  datea         montantA    Salarie_id
1   11/03/2020    120          1
2   02/03/2020    50           1
```

by these 3 tables I want to recover salaries.id and salaries.name and sum (pointages.sold) and sum (avances.montantA) like
this

```
Salarie.id  Salaries.nom    Sum(sold)   Sum(montantA)
1              kamal           220          170
2              imad            70           0
```

I execute this function etatq1u of controller but it gives me erroneous sums and a single record salaries1 because not have a avance for record 2 (salaries 2).
here is error result which gives me:

```
id:1
nom:kamal
sold:440
montantA:340
```

**SalarieController.php**

```
public function etatq1u(request $request){

      $dataP = DB::table('salaries')
         ->join('pointages','pointages.salarie_id','salaries.id')
         ->join('avances','avances.salarie_id','salaries.id')
          ->selectRaw('salaries.id,salaries.nom,SUM(pointages.sold) as sold,SUM(avances.montantA) as avance')
          ->groupBy('pointages.salarie_id')
          ->get();
          return response($dataP);
}
```

**etatq1.balde.php**

```
 $.ajax({
          type: 'get',
          url: "{{ route('salarie.etatq1u') }}",
          data: {
                 'annee':ann,
                 'mois':moi,
                 'salarie_id':sal,
                 'chantier_id':chan,
                 'unite' : unite
                },
          success: function(data1){
              console.log(data1);
          },
          error: function(){
              console.log('error');
          },
          });
```

Comment: What has this to do with jQuery?

Comment: @Andreas no nothing just to complete the question

Comment: Does this help you:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34557952/mysql-getting-sum-of-a-table-by-the-id-of-its-parent-from-other-table-and-retur

Comment: If this is Laravel, you should not need to use DB facade at all. Relationships should be creating these joins automatically. Something like `Salary::select(['id', 'nom'])->with(['pointages', 'avances'])->sum('pointages.sold')->sum('avances.montantA')->groupBy('id');`

Answer (score 0):

use **UNION** because table avances does not contains imad's data

```
    SELECT
      id
      , name
      , SUM(sold) as sold
      , SUM(montantA) as avance 
    FROM
      ( 
        SELECT
          salaries.id
          , name
          , sold
          , null as montantA 
        FROM
          salaries 
        LEFT JOIN 
            pointages 
        ON salaries.id = pointages.Salarie_id 

        UNION 

        SELECT
          salaries.id
          , name
          , null as sold
          , montantA 
        FROM
          salaries 
        LEFT JOIN 
            avances 
        ON salaries.id = avances.Salarie_id
      ) tbl 
    group by
      tbl.id
```